# How to attach busboy file stream to request body without using intermediate buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, buffer, busboy

I have a Fastify plugin that reads form data using `busboy`. Here is the relevant code:

```
const bus = busboy({ headers: message.headers, limits: options });
bus.on("file", (fieldName: string, file: Readable, fileInfo: FileInfo) => {
    const chunks: Array<Uint8Array> = [];
    const fileObject = new File(fileInfo);
    fileObject.fieldName = fieldName;
    file.on("data", chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
    file.on("close", () => {
        fileObject.data = Readable.from(Buffer.concat(chunks));
        fileList.push(fileObject);
        formData[fieldName] = JSON.stringify(fileInfo);
    });
});
```

Is there a way I can skip the `file.on("data", chunk => chunks.push(chunk));` and `Readable.from(Buffer.concat(chunks))` parts and just put the `file` object in `fileObject.data` instead? I tried using `pipe` and all but the `close` event never fires unless I listen to the `data` event. Please help!

Comment: Trying to mention the author of busboy [mscdex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73111609/930925).

Comment: https://github.com/fastify/fastify-multipart#parse-all-fields-and-assign-them-to-the-body